# Difference between enum behavior with Python

Tags: python, heroku, enums

Here's Python 2.7.6 on my Ubuntu laptop:

```
(myenv)$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import enum
>>> class Fruit(enum.Enum):
...     apple=1
...     orange=2
... 
>>> Fruit.apple
<Fruit.apple: 1>
>>> type(Fruit.apple)
<enum 'Fruit'>
```

and here's it on Heroku (also 2.7.6):

```
~ $ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jul 15 2014, 15:38:10) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import enum
>>> class Fruit(enum.Enum):
...     apple=1
...     orange=2
... 
>>> Fruit.apple
1
>>> type(Fruit.apple)
<type 'int'>
```

EDIT: My requirements.txt file contains this line:

```
enum==0.4.4
```

This is legitimately causing issues as my production version exhibits bugs the local version does not!

Comment: Are you sure you've installed the same package on both machines?

Comment: well both I and heroku use pip, so I was assuming so. perhaps I'm misunderstanding how heroku works? see my edit to the question

Comment: It looks like you've installed [enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) on your local system and [enum](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum) on Heroku server.

Comment: more, accurate: both were installed. does Python not report when such a collison happens? how does it choose which identically named package to use?

Comment: Whichever comes first in the module search path is selected.

Comment: Since both `enum`s are third-party and have the same module name, the second one probably overwrote the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your ubuntu version is the [enum34 backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), while the heroku version is the older `enum` package.

If I read your question correctly and the version with `enum34` is working properly, change your requirements file to use it instead.

Comment: yes, indeed as I mentioned in the comments. just for understanding however, both were installed. does Python not report when such a collison happens? how does it choose which identically named package to use?

Comment: Both install to the same location, so whichever one was installed last wins.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import enum
>>> enum.__version__
'0.4.4'
```

Try checking `enum.__version__`.

Comment: yes, my apologies, added the line in the `requirements.txt` to the question. the package is [enum](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum)

Answer (score 1):

Check the versions of enum library. In your env there is probably older and deprecated version. Anyway field inside enum class must be of its declared type, which in your case is int.

```
...     apple=1
...     orange=2
```

and type of

```
fruit = Fruit
```

would be Fruit